Reading application.properties and other properties files outside the JAR in same folder
I have a requirement to read application.properties values and other properties file outside the JAR. When developing in IDE, I placed the application.properties and other properties file in the same root as src. When running in IDE, it was working fine. But when I made a JAR and placed in a separate folder along with necessary properties file, it is unable to read the same. I believe, I am very close to it. Need help on where I might be wrong. Sharing necessary code snippets.
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class) // Load external properties
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        // Fetch the port from external properties
        String port = System.getProperty("server.port", "8081");
        // openLandingPageInBrowser("http://localhost:" + port);
    }
   }

File where I try to read application.properties
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
public class AppProperties {
    private String port;

    public String getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(String port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
}

File where I read other .properties files
@Service
public class DropdownPropertiesService {

    @Value("${dropdown1.file}")
    private String dropdown1File;

    @Value("${dropdown2.file}")
    private String dropdown2File;
}

application.properties file
spring.application.name=demo2
server.port=8084
dropdown1.file=./dropdown1.properties
dropdown2.file=./dropdown2.properties


Spring Boot will automatically load the application.properties if it is in the same directory as the jar or in a config directory. Your file doesn't have a application.port property, so not sure why you use the prefix application` for that.

so, I need to remove (prefix="application") and add application.port and remove server.port ?

server.port is used by Spring Boot to configure the port used to start the embedded container. I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve with the AppProperties (it shouldn't be an @Configuration class either). If you want access to the server.port use the existing ServerProperties from Spring Boot instead of re-building something yourself.

I am trying to create a JAR (with some implementation which opens a Browser window/Tab with landing page) for Non-technical people. So, want to put the configurable values including the port on which the application starts/run. For that I have done like that. and it worked fine in IDE. But not as a JAR.

Is my approach wrong for my requirement ?

As stated you don't need additional classes for that use the ServerProperties. Ify ou are creating the jar correctly with the spring boot plugin spring boot will handle the loading mapping etc. no need to add an additional class for that.

ok, will try to do that.

Project Tree
demo-spring-boot-props
├── pom.xml
├── config1
│   └── application.properties
├── config2
│   └── application.properties
├── dropdown1.properties
├── dropdown2.properties
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           ├── AppConfig.java
        │           ├── DemoApplication.java
        │           └── HelloController.java
        └── resources
            └── application.properties

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-spring-boot-props</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-spring-boot-props</name>
    <description>demo-spring-boot-props project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>        
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

resources/application.properties
spring.application.name=demo
# greeting=Hello
greeting=${GREETING:Hello}

DemoApplication.java
default , template.
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

HelloController.java
Test Class
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    AppConfig appConfig;

    //Inject greeting property from application.properties
    // If GREETING is set in the environment variable, this value will be used first; otherwise, the greeting value in application.properties will be used.
    @Value("${greeting:NotDefine}")
    private String greeting;

    @Value("${dropdown1.file:NotDefine}")
    private String dropdown1File;

    @Value("${dropdown2.file:NotDefine}")
    private String dropdown2File;

    // Create a GET request to receive parameters
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(@RequestParam(value = "msg", defaultValue = "World") String msg) {
        return String.format("%s, %s!", greeting, msg);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getFile1")
    public String getFile1() {
        return dropdown1File;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getFile2")
    public String getFile2() {
        return dropdown2File;
    }

    @GetMapping("/dump")
    public String deump() {
        return appConfig.dump();
    }
}

AppConfig.java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
//@PropertySource("classpath:config1.properties")
//@PropertySource("classpath:config2.properties")
//@PropertySource("classpath:${dropdown1.file:NotDefine}")
//@PropertySource("classpath:${dropdown2.file:NotDefine}")
// ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [dropdown1.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

@PropertySource("file:${dropdown1.file:NotDefine}")
@PropertySource("file:${dropdown2.file:NotDefine}")
public class AppConfig {
    @Value("${AAA1:NotDefine}")
    private String aaa1;
    @Value("${BBB1:NotDefine}")
    private String bbb1;
    @Value("${CCC1:NotDefine}")
    private String ccc1;
    @Value("${AAA2:NotDefine}")
    private String aaa2;
    @Value("${BBB2:NotDefine}")
    private String bbb2;
    @Value("${CCC2:NotDefine}")
    private String ccc2;

    @Value("${AAA3:NotDefine}")
    private String aaa3;
    @Value("${BBB3:NotDefine}")
    private String bbb3;
    @Value("${CCC3:NotDefine}")
    private String ccc3;

    public String dump() {
        String sb = "aaa1 = " + aaa1 + "\n" +
                "bbb1 = " + bbb1 + "\n" +
                "ccc1 = " + ccc1 + "\n" +
                "aaa2 = " + aaa2 + "\n" +
                "bbb2 = " + bbb2 + "\n" +
                "ccc2 = " + ccc2 + "\n" +
                "aaa3 = " + aaa3 + "\n" +
                "bbb3 = " + bbb3 + "\n" +
                "ccc3 = " + ccc3 + "\n";
        return sb;
    }
}

config1/application.properties
dropdown1.file=./dropdown1.properties

config2/application.properties
dropdown2.file=./dropdown2.properties

dropdown1.properties
AAA1=XXXa1
BBB1=XXXb1
CCC1=XXXc1

dropdown2.properties
AAA2=YYYa2
BBB2=YYYb2
CCC2=YYYc2

Build
mvn clean package

Run
Linux
export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=classpath:/application.properties,optional:file:`pwd`/config1/application.properties,optional:file:`pwd`/config2/application.properties

java -jar target/app.jar

You can config application.properties by setting environment variable: SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION
I config 3 application.properties.

(1) app.jar/application.properties read it by clsspath

classpath:/application.properties


(2) config1/application.properties by file path

file:`pwd`/config1/application.properties


(3) config2/application.properties by file path

file:`pwd`/config2/application.properties

demo-spring-boot-props
├── target
│   └── app.jar/application.properties (classpath)
├── config1
│   └── application.properties
└── config2
    └── application.properties

Test
Test1
curl http://localhost:8080/hello?msg=Spring
>>> Hello, Spring!

curl http://localhost:8080/hello
>>> Hello, World!

Setting Property greeting by environment GREETING
Stop spring boot application (Ctrl + C)
Linux
export GREETING=XYZ

java -jar target/app.jar

Test2
curl http://localhost:8080/hello?msg=Spring
>>> XYZ, Spring!

curl http://localhost:8080/hello
>>> XYZ, World!

The greeting attribute can be read from application.perties or set through the environment variable GREETING.
# application.properties
greeting=${GREETING:Hello}

Test 3
curl http://localhost:8080/getFile1
>>> ./dropdown1.properties

curl http://localhost:8080/getFile2
>>> ./dropdown2.properties

HelloController.java read dropdown1.file and dropdown2.file.
@Value("${dropdown1.file:NotDefine}")
private String dropdown1File;

@Value("${dropdown2.file:NotDefine}")
private String dropdown2File;

But where do the settings for the dropdown1.file and dropdown2.file properties come from?
Remember this?
export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=classpath:/application.properties,optional:file:`pwd`/config1/application.properties,optional:file:`pwd`/config2/application.properties

config1/application.properties and config2/application.properties provides dropdown1.file and dropdown2.file config
# config1/application.properties
dropdown1.file=./dropdown1.properties

config2/application.properties
dropdown2.file=./dropdown2.properties

demo-spring-boot-props
├── dropdown1.properties
└── dropdown2.properties

Test 3
curl http://localhost:8080/dump

aaa1 = XXXa1
bbb1 = XXXb1
ccc1 = XXXc1
aaa2 = YYYa2
bbb2 = YYYb2
ccc2 = YYYc2
aaa3 = NotDefine
bbb3 = NotDefine
ccc3 = NotDefine

Stop spring boot application (Ctrl + C)
Change server port by spring application parameter.
java -jar target/app.jar --server.port=8888

Test 4
curl http://localhost:8888/hello?msg=Spring
>>> XYZ, Spring!

Summarize:
(1) Spring Boot Application’s Property can be read from multiple sources.

Read directly from application.properties
Set environment variables.
Read from Spring Boot Application app parameter.

(2) Spring Boot’s application.properties also comes from multiple sources.

Can be obtained from application.properties (classpath) in the application jar
Can command paths from external directories.

